# How do I cleanly interpolate a column reference into a PostgreSQL query with Peewee?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, peewee

I am attempting to execute an INSERT...ON CONFLICT...UPDATE query on a PostgreSQL database using Peewee, I want to keep the columns I'm updating dynamic, but when I use the native interpolation the database adds single quotes around my columns, how do I fix this?

```
updates = {
    'column1': 'value1',
    'column2': 'value2'
}
cols = tuple(updates.keys())
vals = tuple(updates.values())
ids = list(peewee.RawQuery(Table_Model,
    "INSERT INTO table %s VALUES %s \
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT constraint_name \
        DO UPDATE SET %s = %s \
    RETURNING id;",
    cols, vals, cols, vals).dicts())
```

I get the following error:

```
syntax error at or near "'column1'"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO table ('column1', 'column...
```

Note: I am using raw SQL because as far as I can tell Peewee does not yet support .on_conflict() for PostgreSQL, but if I'm wrong about that PLEASE tell me and I can revise.

Comment: Peewee 3.0a does support ON CONFLICT. Example: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/f1f1d0eaae0b2ebf2a14c3c3665bff9a7a511634/tests/models.py#L1334-L1359

Comment: Super helpful, while I'm a little skeptical of using this alpha release, I'll give it a go!